# Ajax function with Jquery returns 400 error

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I'm using `Jquery` with `Spring MVC`.

I have an `index.jsp`:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input").keyup(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : "myController",
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#name").val(),
                success : function(result) {

                    alert(result);
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="text" class="form-name" id="name" placeholder="Paolo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see when one inserts a letter in the input box I run `$ajax` with jQuery. 
My HTTP POST request is correclty sent but I have a 400 error.

This is my simple Controller class:

```
    @Controller
public class MyController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/myController", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    @ResponseBody
    public String getData(@RequestParam(value="name") String name) {

        return name;    
    }
}
```

My DispatcherServlet for Spring MVC is correclty setted. 
How can I solve?

Comment: Try with `data: { name : $("#name").val(), }`

Comment: I have tried but it does not work. I have the same 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the server, when you got this eror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules.

Your ajax call would be

```
$.ajax({
        url : "myController",
        type: "POST",
        data:{"name": $("#name").val()},
        success : function(result) {                       
                 alert(result);
               }

       });
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. 
So I have to format my request in key-value pairs, right?